# Salable Quantity in Magento 2.3 don't show

Tags: php, magento2

I have a problem with Salable Quantity in Magento 2.3

After importing products, entering the catalog and no product has Salable Quantity. I do not know why.

If I enter to edit the product and without changing anything I save it, the product appears with the Salable Quantity field. Why? If I just save, I don't change anything?

I'm frustrated.

I import products with a .csv file with these fields.

```
sku: VAL-LIGA-12

attribute_set_code: Default

product_type: simple

product_online: 1

qty: 100

is_in_stock: 1
```

I appreciate any help to import products with the Salable Quantity field.

I enclose a screenshot.

Regards.

[Screenshot Backend](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hckM4.png)

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this as I have the same issue?

Comment: did anyone find it?

Answer (score 6):

Your issue looks similar to mine.

I removed MSI when installing Magento 2 - Then after purchasing an ebay plugin we needed MSI - so then I re-installed it - and like you - my "Saleable Quantity" was blank - not 0 - blank.

[My product with blank saleable quantity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W1sz2.png)

After a load of googling and looking at other posts - I found I'd f****d the db.

My 'inventory_source_item' was empty - so to fix this I found a post on here:

```
https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/294286/after-migration-inventory-source-item-table-is-empty-magneto-2
```

The SQL provided fixed the 'inventory_source_item' table.

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO `inventory_source_item` (source_code, sku, quantity, status) select 'default', sku, qty, stock_status from (`cataloginventory_stock_status` as `lg` join `catalog_product_entity` as `prd` on((`lg`.`product_id` = `prd`.`entity_id`)))
```

^ Important: here 'default' is the source_code of your stock source - if yours is like mine then the SQL should work as is, otherwise change 'default' to 'yourstocksourcecode' ^

[My stock sources](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M6Z1D.png)

but still my "Saleable Quantity" was blank.

Then I noticed the 'inventory_source_item_link' table was empty. I simply inserted 1 row:

```
INSERT INTO `inventory_source_stock_link` (`link_id`, `stock_id`, `source_code`, `priority`) VALUES ('1', '1', 'default', '1');
```

and now my Saleable Quantity is there  1 row doesn't have it because its just the grouped product...

[My products showing saleable quantity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LqWfo.png)

It's also worth pointing out - after the final SQL I re-indexed to make sure it would be there:

```
php bin/magento indexer:reset && php bin/magento indexer:reindex
```

Comment: Thank you!! That solved my issue in Magento 2.4.1 Cloud too.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I disabled extension "php bin/magento module:disable BoostMyShop_AdvancedStock" and stock issue resolved.

Thanks,